# Why is Data.fs.old disappearing?

Tags: plone, packing, zodb

I am testing the packing-mechanism, therefore setted `pack-days` to zero, added and removed objects via ZMI to generate some history, and execute `zeopack`, which works fine so far.

Yet, if there hasn't been any transactions since the last packing, and another new packing is triggered, the Data.fs.old is deleted/disappears, why?

Respectively, which codelines are doing that? Cannot find it somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting a pack *always* removes the `.old` file.

When there then is nothing to pack, no *new* `.old` file is created in it's place.

See the [`FileStorage.pack()` method](https://github.com/zopefoundation/ZODB/blob/96a9413fa7d77176fad4c0af4c580a572476d14e/src/ZODB/FileStorage/FileStorage.py#L1081); it deletes an existing `.old` file right after acquiring the packing lock.

The logic goes (with some indentation and intermediary code removed):

```
oldpath = self._file_name + ".old"
if os.path.exists(oldpath):
    os.remove(oldpath)

# collect pack info
pack_result = self.packer(self, referencesf, stop, gc)

if pack_result is None:
    return

os.rename(self._file_name, oldpath)
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Seems, I was not grepping well enough :) Just for couriosity, as I am aware of, that this is negligible, if one does (better so) regulary snapshots: As Data.fs.old is ment to be a kind of backup, it should remain even in this case (no action happened since last pack), IMHO. Do you see that likely?

Comment: Not really; the `.old` file is more meant as a safeguard here; if the pack goes wrong you have the old version. If you first pack to 1 day, then one day later pack to two days, there might now not be anything to pack but `.old` is not the same ZODB as what you just tried to pack. It wouldn't be an accurate backup. I'd rather remove `.old` in all cases and avoid chances of confusion, and in any case use `repoze` to create proper incremental backups.

Comment: Now everything makes sense, appreciate you openness to discuss, gracias!

Comment: Thank *you* for asking ZODB questions! :-P 4 more questions and the tag becomes eligible for tag badges, I'd be proud to earn a ZODB bronze badge.

Comment: Well, if any more ZODB quest comes up to my mind, be sure, I'll post it right away, without hesitation nor doing any research then, just to do you a favour ;)

Comment: Here you are: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026321/how-to-define-db-location-in-a-plone-4-1-unified-zeo-install

Comment: Hehe, enough questions have been asked in the meantime that I did earn that bronze badge already: http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3294/zodb

Comment: Congrats, pioneer! :)