# How to define DB-location in a Plone-4.1-Unified-Zeo-Install?

Tags: plone, zodb

In Plone's 4.3.1-Unified-Installer's base.cfg (ZEO) I can see, it is possible to define the ZODB-location as a variable, in Plone-4.1.6-Unfied-Installer's base.cfg, not.

Before I start investigating further: Is is it possible to mimicry this in 4.1 by simply adjusting the config, or does this option depend on higher core-package-versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do it by adjusting the 4.1.x config. The 4.3.x feature was just an enhancement of the installer; the ability to do it has always been present in the plone.recipe.zope* recipes.

Comment: Nice :) And thanks very much for the great work on providing the Unified-Installers!